# to do list task with components pure javascript

Tags: javascript, components

have a to do list task.
there are three components. class TodoAppComponent, class TodoFormComponent and class TodoListComponent.
inspect my doneTask() in TodoListComponent please.
when I add a task I need to cross the row when state of checkbox change to 'checked'
it seems doesn't work properly but console doesn't show any mistakes

```js
class TodoAppComponent {
  constructor(mountPoint, props = {}) {
    this.mountPoint = mountPoint;
    this.props = props;
  }

  querySelectors() {
    this.todoFormMountPoint = this.mountPoint.querySelector(
      ".todo-app__form-point"
    );
    this.todoListMountPoint = this.mountPoint.querySelector(
      ".todo-app__list-point"
    );
  }

  mountChildren() {
    this.todoFormComponent = new TodoFormComponent(this.todoFormMountPoint, {
      onTodoAdd: this.handleTodoAdd.bind(this)
    });
    this.todoFormComponent.mount();
    this.todoListComponent = new TodoListComponent(this.todoListMountPoint);
    this.todoListComponent.mount();
  }

  handleTodoAdd(task) {
    this.todoListComponent.addTask(task);
    const numItems = this.todoListComponent.getNumTasks();
    this.todoFormComponent.setCounter(numItems + 1);
  }

  mount() {
    this.mountPoint.innerHTML = this.render();
    this.querySelectors();
    this.mountChildren();
  }

  render() {
    return `
      <div class="todo-app">
        <h2>Todo:</h2>
        <div class="todo-app__form-point"></div>
        <div class="todo-app__list-point"></div>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

class TodoFormComponent {
  constructor(mountPoint, props = {}) {
    this.mountPoint = mountPoint;
    this.props = props;
  }

  querySelectors() {
    this.field = this.mountPoint.querySelector(".todo-form__field");
    this.btn = this.mountPoint.querySelector(".todo-form__btn");
    this.counter = this.mountPoint.querySelector(".todo-form__counter");
  }

  addEventListeners() {
    this.btn.addEventListener("click", this.handeBtnClick.bind(this));
  }

  handeBtnClick() {
    this.props.onTodoAdd(this.field.value);
    this.field.value = "";
  }

  mount() {
    this.mountPoint.innerHTML = this.render();
    this.querySelectors();
    this.addEventListeners();
  }

  setCounter(val) {
    this.counter.innerHTML = val;
  }

  render() {
    return `
      <div class="todo-form">
        <input class="todo-form__field" type="text">
        <button class="todo-form__btn">
          Add #<span class="todo-form__counter">1</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

class TodoListComponent {
  constructor(mountPoint, props = {}) {
    this.mountPoint = mountPoint;
    this.props = props;
  }

  querySelectors() {
    this.list = this.mountPoint.querySelector(".todo-list");
  }

  mount() {
    this.mountPoint.innerHTML = this.render();
    this.querySelectors();
    this.doneTask();
  }

  addTask(task) {
    this.list.innerHTML += `
    <tr><td><input class ="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>${task}</td>
    <td><button value="&#215" style="width:5px;height:15px;"></button></td></tr>
        `;
  }

  doneTask() {
    let checkboxElements = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");

    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxElements.length; i++) {
      checkboxElements[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          this.closest("tr").style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        }
      });
    }
  }
  getNumTasks() {
    return this.list.children.length;
  }

  render() {
    return `
      <br>
      <table class="todo-list" style="width:50px"></table>
    `;
  }
}

const root = document.querySelector("#root");

const cmp = new TodoAppComponent(root);

cmp.mount();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think the problem her is in your addTask method. You just add checbox ass html, but you do not add any listener that is going to call the doneTask when the added checbox is checked.

Comment: your function doneTask(), is not getting called whenever the checkbox is being checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
class TodoAppComponent {
  constructor(mountPoint, props = {}) {
    this.mountPoint = mountPoint;
    this.props = props;
  }

  querySelectors() {
    this.todoFormMountPoint = this.mountPoint.querySelector(
      ".todo-app__form-point"
    );
    this.todoListMountPoint = this.mountPoint.querySelector(
      ".todo-app__list-point"
    );
  }

  mountChildren() {
    this.todoFormComponent = new TodoFormComponent(this.todoFormMountPoint, {
      onTodoAdd: this.handleTodoAdd.bind(this)
    });
    this.todoFormComponent.mount();
    this.todoListComponent = new TodoListComponent(this.todoListMountPoint);
    this.todoListComponent.mount();
  }

  handleTodoAdd(task) {
    this.todoListComponent.addTask(task);
    const numItems = this.todoListComponent.getNumTasks();
    this.todoFormComponent.setCounter(numItems + 1);
  }

  mount() {
    this.mountPoint.innerHTML = this.render();
    this.querySelectors();
    this.mountChildren();
  }

  render() {
    return `
      <div class="todo-app">
        <h2>Todo:</h2>
        <div class="todo-app__form-point"></div>
        <div class="todo-app__list-point"></div>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

class TodoFormComponent {
  constructor(mountPoint, props = {}) {
    this.mountPoint = mountPoint;
    this.props = props;
  }

  querySelectors() {
    this.field = this.mountPoint.querySelector(".todo-form__field");
    this.btn = this.mountPoint.querySelector(".todo-form__btn");
    this.counter = this.mountPoint.querySelector(".todo-form__counter");
  }

  addEventListeners() {
    this.btn.addEventListener("click", this.handeBtnClick.bind(this));
  }

  handeBtnClick() {
    this.props.onTodoAdd(this.field.value);
    this.field.value = "";
  }

  mount() {
    this.mountPoint.innerHTML = this.render();
    this.querySelectors();
    this.addEventListeners();
  }

  setCounter(val) {
    this.counter.innerHTML = val;
  }

  render() {
    return `
      <div class="todo-form">
        <input class="todo-form__field" type="text">
        <button class="todo-form__btn">
          Add #<span class="todo-form__counter">1</span>
        </button>
      </div>
    `;
  }
}

class TodoListComponent {
  constructor(mountPoint, props = {}) {
    this.mountPoint = mountPoint;
    this.props = props;
  }

  querySelectors() {
    this.list = this.mountPoint.querySelector(".todo-list");
  }

  mount() {
    this.mountPoint.innerHTML = this.render();
    this.querySelectors();
    this.doneTask();
  }

  addTask(task) {
    this.list.innerHTML += `
    <tr><td><input class ="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>${task}</td>
    <td><button value="&#215" style="width:5px;height:15px;"></button></td></tr>
        `;
        
     this.doneTask();
  }

  doneTask() {
    let checkboxElements = document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox");

    for (let i = 0; i < checkboxElements.length; i++) {
      checkboxElements[i].addEventListener("change", function() {
        if (this.checked) {
          this.closest("tr").style.textDecoration = "line-through";
        }
      });
    }
  }
  getNumTasks() {
    return this.list.children.length;
  }

  render() {
    return `
      <br>
      <table class="todo-list" style="width:50px"></table>
    `;
  }
}

const root = document.querySelector("#root");

const cmp = new TodoAppComponent(root);

cmp.mount();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Because your function `doneTask()` was not getting called, that's why the style was not updating. Try this. 
I just called `doneTask()` in `addTask()`.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

The method `doneTask()` runs only once, in the initialization of the page, to add the listeners. At this point there are actually no elements and therefore no listeners are added.

Instead, try to add a listener to each element you add to the DOM (so `doneTask()` is redundant):

```
  addTask(task) {
    this.list.innerHTML += `
    <tr><td><input class ="checkbox" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>${task}</td>
    <td><button value="&#215" style="width:5px;height:15px;"></button></td></tr>
        `;

    // Actually add the listener
    this.list.lastChild.firstChild.firstChild.firstChild.addEventListener("change", function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        this.closest("tr").style.textDecoration = "line-through";
      }
    });

  }
```